# I've to integrate shippingHQ in my project with codeigniter, want to know is it possible? I am not getting relevant details on shippingHQ portal

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've to **integrate shippingHQ** in my project **with codeigniter**, want to know is it possible? I am not getting relevant details on shippingHQ portal.

I have checked the shippingHQ website links also..

```
https://docs.shipperhq.com/website-configuration/#API_Integrations
```

&

```
https://docs.shipperhq.com/graphql-sandbox-usage/
```

But I am not getting how to integrate shippingHQ with codeigniter, please suggest me links or any custom libraries are there?

Comment: CodeIgniter is just PHP. If a framework would hinder you to use different API's/SDK's or what ever you need to do, it would be completely pointless and counter productive. Now, if you have some _specific_ issue you want help with, please edit your question and clarify it, together with all relevant code, example input, expected output and what currently happens.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are right.. integration of any kind of api with php.. its also a part of php.. isn't it?

Comment: What's your point with the last comment? Do you have some specific question/issue? What answer are you expecting to get here?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson just want to know above integration is possible or not?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? Again, **if you have some specific issue**, please edit your question to _include all relevant info_. If you can make an integration in PHP, then you should be able to do it any framework as well.

Comment: The last part of your question is off-topic though. Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - _"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"_